# How to cancel printing in ReportViewer1.Print Event?

Tags: .net, vb.net, reporting-services, rdlc, reportviewer

I created ReportViewer1. It will show preview and I need to cancel print out to a printer when the user clicks a Print Button on the toolbar.

Like this

```
Private Sub ReportViewer1_Print(sender As Object, e As ReportPrintEventArgs) _
  Handles ReportViewer1.Print
    Me.ReportViewer1.CancelRendering(0)   ''/ <----Cancel Printing
    RaiseEvent Click_Print(False)
End Sub
```

But CancelRendering is not working because it shows dialogSetting for the selected printer.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop print event using this code:

```
Private Sub ReportViewer1_Print(sender As Object, e As Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportPrintEventArgs) Handles ReportViewer1.Print

    e.Cancel = True

    MsgBox("Print stopped!")

End Sub
```

If you don't want to permit printing maybe it is better hide print button setting [`ShowPrintButton`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportviewer.showprintbutton(v=vs.120).aspx) property to `False`.